# Monitor API activities of Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure

I would like to monitor and log API activities in Azure Blob Storage to a container of a storage account. I already implemented monitoring to a storage account from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account) but it is not enough. I expect to have more detailed log messages of API activities similar to AWS Cloudtrail or Google Stackdriver. I found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/storage-insights-overview) of using Monitor service to monitor the storage account but I could not see any information about detailed log message of API activities. Is there any alternatives to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new (in preview) change feed feature of Azure Blobs. This will log all activities on blobs in your storage account. You can see how to enable this here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-change-feed?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: what is the difference in terms of the log format with https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/monitor-storage?tabs=azure-powershell? Which one has more complete information?